# How to generate Image Histogram in Android?

Tags: android, histogram

I tried to generate histogram of Image using following code,

```
package com.example.viewfinderee368;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
public class HistogramDemo extends Activity {

    Bitmap mainImage;
    Bitmap histroImage;

    ImageView mainImageView;
    LinearLayout histroImageView;

    private DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.histrogram);

        mainImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        histroImageView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.histroImg);

        mainImage = ((BitmapDrawable) mainImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        histroImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainImage);

        mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);

          mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth = mainImage.getWidth();
          mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight = mainImage.getHeight();
          mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 
                  mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
          mDrawOnTop.mRGBData = new int[mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth * mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight]; 

          int bytes = mainImage.getByteCount();
          //or we can calculate bytes this way. Use a different value than 4 if you don't use 32bit images.
          //int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4; 

            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
            mainImage.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer


            byte[] array = buffer.array();
          mDrawOnTop.mYUVData =array;  

          System.arraycopy(array, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, array.length);
//        mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
          histroImageView.addView(mDrawOnTop);

    }

    class DrawOnTop extends View {
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        Paint mPaintBlack;
        Paint mPaintYellow;
        Paint mPaintRed;
        Paint mPaintGreen;
        Paint mPaintBlue;
        Paint mPaintGray;

        byte[] mYUVData;
        int[] mRGBData;
        int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
        int[] mRedHistogram;
        int[] mGreenHistogram;
        int[] mBlueHistogram;
        double[] mBinSquared;

        private DrawOnTop(Context context) {
            super(context);

            mPaintBlack = new Paint();
            mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mPaintBlack.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintYellow = new Paint();
            mPaintYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mPaintYellow.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintRed = new Paint();
            mPaintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintRed.setColor(Color.RED);
            mPaintRed.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintGreen = new Paint();
            mPaintGreen.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mPaintGreen.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintBlue = new Paint();
            mPaintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaintBlue.setTextSize(25);

            mPaintGray = new Paint();
            mPaintGray.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mPaintGray.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            mPaintGray.setTextSize(25);


            mBitmap = null;
            mYUVData = null;
            mRGBData = null;
            mRedHistogram = new int[256];
            mGreenHistogram = new int[256];
            mBlueHistogram = new int[256];
            mBinSquared = new double[256];
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                mBinSquared[bin] = ((double)bin) * bin;
            } // bin
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            if (mBitmap != null)
            {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                int canvasWidth = 255;
                int canvasHeight =255;
                int newImageWidth = canvasWidth;
                int newImageHeight = canvasHeight;
                int marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

                // Convert from YUV to RGB
                decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

                // Draw bitmap
                mBitmap.setPixels(mRGBData, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

                // Draw black borders                       
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0, marginWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);
                canvas.drawRect(canvasWidth - marginWidth, 0, 
                        canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);

                // Calculate histogram
                calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 0);
                calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mGreenHistogram, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 1);
                calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mBlueHistogram, 
                        mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 2);

                // Calculate mean
                double imageRedMean = 0, imageGreenMean = 0, imageBlueMean = 0;
                double redHistogramSum = 0, greenHistogramSum = 0, blueHistogramSum = 0;

                    for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
                {
                    imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
                    redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
                    imageGreenMean += mGreenHistogram[bin] * bin;
                    greenHistogramSum += mGreenHistogram[bin];
                    imageBlueMean += mBlueHistogram[bin] * bin;
                    blueHistogramSum += mBlueHistogram[bin];
                } // bin
                imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
                imageGreenMean /= greenHistogramSum;
                imageBlueMean /= blueHistogramSum;

                // Draw red intensity histogram
                float barMaxHeight = 5000;
                float barWidth = ((float)newImageWidth) / 256;
                float barMarginHeight = 2;
                RectF barRect = new RectF();
                barRect.bottom = canvasHeight -50 ;
                barRect.left = marginWidth;
                barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 255; bin++)
                {
                    float prob = (float)mRedHistogram[bin] / (float)redHistogramSum;
                    barRect.top = barRect.bottom - 
                        Math.min(100,prob*barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                    barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGray);
                    barRect.left += barWidth;
                    barRect.right += barWidth;
                } // bin

                // Draw green intensity histogram
                barRect.bottom = canvasHeight -50 ;
                barRect.left = marginWidth;
                barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 255; bin++)
                {
                    barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(100, ((float)mGreenHistogram[bin])/((float)greenHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                    barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGray);
                    barRect.left += barWidth;
                    barRect.right += barWidth;
                } // bin

                // Draw blue intensity histogram
                barRect.bottom = canvasHeight -50 ;
                barRect.left = marginWidth;
                barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
                for (int bin = 0; bin < 255; bin++)
                {
                    barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(100, ((float)mBlueHistogram[bin])/((float)blueHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                    barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                    canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGray);
                    barRect.left += barWidth;
                    barRect.right += barWidth;
                } // bin
            } // end if statement

            super.onDraw(canvas);

        }

        private void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            final int frameSize = width * height;

            for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                    int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                    if (y < 0) y = 0;
                    if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                        v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                        u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    }

                    int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                    int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                    int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                    int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                    if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                    if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                    if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                    rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
                }
            }
        }


        private void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram, int width, int height, int component)
        {
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                histogram[bin] = 0;
            } // bin
            if (component == 0) // red
            {
                for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
                {
                    int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
                    histogram[ pixVal ]++;
                } // pix
            }
            else if (component == 1) // green
            {
                for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
                {
                    int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
                    histogram[ pixVal ]++;
                } // pix
            }
            else // blue
            {
                for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
                {
                    int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
                    histogram[ pixVal ]++;
                } // pix
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

But its not generating reliable histogram, I need to generate same histogram as in Adobe Photoshop. 
 In **ios** its generating same histogram as in Adobe Photoshop using following code.

```
 -(void)readImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
//    NSLog(@"histogram width:- %d",width);
//    NSLog(@"histogram height:- %d",height);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    for (int yy=0;yy<height; yy++)
    {
        for (int xx=0; xx<width; xx++)
        {
            // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
            int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
            for (int ii = 0 ; ii < 1 ; ++ii)
            {
                CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) ;
                CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) ;
                CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) ;
                // CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
                byteIndex += 4;

                // TYPE CASTING ABOVE FLOAT VALUES TO THAT THEY CAN BE MATCHED WITH ARRAY'S INDEX.

                int redValue = (int)red;
                int greenValue = (int)green;
                int blueValue = (int)blue;


                // THESE COUNTERS COUNT " TOTAL NUMBER OF PIXELS " FOR THAT  Red , Green or Blue Value IN ENTIRE IMAGE.

                fltR[redValue]++;
                fltG[greenValue]++;
                fltB[blueValue]++;
            }
        }
    }
    [self makeArrays];


//    for (int yy=0;yy<height; yy++)
//    {
//        for (int xx=0; xx<width; xx++)
//        {
//            int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
//            rawData [byteIndex] = nil;
//        }
//    }
//    rawData = 0;
//    rawData = nil;
    static unsigned updateCounter = 0;
    memset(rawData, updateCounter & 0xff, width*height*4);
    free(rawData);
    rawData = NULL;

    for(int i=0;i<=255;i++){
        fltR[i]=0;
        fltG[i]=0;
        fltB[i]=0;
    }
    colorSpace = nil;
}

-(void)makeArrays
{
    float max=0;
    int maxR=0;
    int maxG=0;
    int maxB=0;



    // PERFORMING SUMMESION OF ALL RED , GREEN AND BLUE VLAUES GRADUALLY TO TAKE AVERAGE OF THEM
//    NSLog(@"makeArray :- ,fltR[i]  = %f ,fltG[i]  = %f ,fltB[i] = %f",fltR[i],fltG[i],fltB[i])
    for (int i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
//        NSLog(@"makeArray :- ,fltR[i]  = %f ,fltG[i]  = %f ,fltB[i] = %f",fltR[i],fltG[i],fltB[i]);
        maxR += fltR[i];
        maxG += fltG[i];
        maxB += fltB[i];
    }


    // CALCULATING AVERAGE OF ALL red, green and blue values.
    maxR = maxR/255;
    maxG = maxG/255;
    maxB = maxB/255;


    // As  I AM GENERATING 3 GRAPHS , ITS COMPULSARY TO KEEP THEM ON SCREEN SO TAKING THEIR AVERAGE.
    max = (maxR+maxG+maxB)/3;

    // DEVIDED BY 8 TO GET GRAPH OF THE SAME SIZE AS ITS IN PREVIEW
    max = max*2.5;
    arrAllPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
        ClsDrawPoint *objPoint = [[ClsDrawPoint alloc] init];
        objPoint.x = i;
        objPoint.y = fltR[i]*scale/max;
        [arrAllPoints addObject:objPoint];
    }

    redGraphView.arrRedPoints = arrAllPoints;
//    redGraphView.graphColor = [UIColor redColor];
    redGraphView.graphColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [redGraphView drawGraphForArray:arrAllPoints];       /* redGraphView is an object of ClsDraw (custom class of UIView) and this call drws graph from the points of arrAllPoints */

    arrAllPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
        ClsDrawPoint *objPoint = [[ClsDrawPoint alloc] init];
        objPoint.x = i;
        objPoint.y = fltG[i]*scale/max;
        [arrAllPoints addObject:objPoint];
    }

    greenGraphView.arrRedPoints = arrAllPoints;
//    greenGraphView.graphColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    greenGraphView.graphColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [greenGraphView drawGraphForArray:arrAllPoints];         /* greenGraphView is an object of ClsDraw (custom class of UIView) and this call drws graph from the points of arrAllPoints */

    arrAllPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
        ClsDrawPoint *objPoint = [[ClsDrawPoint alloc] init];
        objPoint.x = i;
        objPoint.y = fltB[i]*scale/max;
        [arrAllPoints addObject:objPoint];
    }
    blueGraphView.arrRedPoints = arrAllPoints;
//    blueGraphView.graphColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    blueGraphView.graphColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [blueGraphView drawGraphForArray:arrAllPoints];         /* blueGraphView is an object of ClsDraw (custom class of UIView) and this call drws graph from the points of arrAllPoints */


    // THE COORDINATE SYSTEM OF IOS IS TOTALLY OPPOSITE TO THAT OF THE MAC'S SO ROTATED IT WITH REFERENCE TO X - axis.
    blueGraphView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0,0.0, 0.0);
    redGraphView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0,0.0, 0.0);
    greenGraphView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0,0.0, 0.0);
}
```

I tried to find Adobe Photoshop android api for it but i didn't find. Is there other api to develop histogram app?

Thanks,

Comment: _"But its not generating reliable histogram"_ is pretty vague. What's actually happening? Also, you posted a large amount of code, most of which is clearly irrelevant to the problem itself. Can you narrow down the problem to a specific part of your code?

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks for reply.. Actually i wanted to generate same histogram as per Adobe Photoshop, and i don't know how Photoshop is generating it. In my code histogram is generated based on RGB values only. But its not same as photoshop & ios code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got the solution & i created colored histogram with following code,

 **EDIT :** 

I have put my complete code,

**DangiAndroidHistogram.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.myandroidhistogram.R;

public class DangiAndroidHistogram extends Activity {

    Bitmap bi = null;

    boolean isColored;

    LinearLayout view;
    LinearLayout view_color;

    boolean flag;

    private int SIZE = 256;
    // Red, Green, Blue
    private int NUMBER_OF_COLOURS = 3;

    public final int RED = 0;
    public final int GREEN = 1;
    public final int BLUE = 2;

    private int[][] colourBins;
    private volatile boolean loaded = false;
    private int maxY;

    private static final int LDPI = 0;
    private static final int MDPI = 1;
    private static final int TVDPI = 2;
    private static final int HDPI = 3;
    private static final int XHDPI = 4;

    float offset = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    

        if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_LOW)
            offset = 0.75f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
            offset = 1f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_TV)
            offset = 1.33f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
            offset = 1.5f;
        else if(metrics.densityDpi==metrics.DENSITY_XHIGH)
            offset = 2f;

        Log.e("NIRAV",""+offset);

        colourBins = new int[NUMBER_OF_COLOURS][];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {
            colourBins[i] = new int[SIZE];
        }

        loaded = false;

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (flag) {
                    view_color.removeAllViews();
                    view.removeAllViews();
                }
                Intent it = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(it, 101);

                flag = true;

                /*
                 * LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt);
                 * view.addView(new MyHistogram(getApplicationContext()));
                 */
            }
        });

        Button histogram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_btn);
        histogram.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (bi != null) {
                    isColored = false;
                    view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt);
                    view.addView(new MyHistogram(getApplicationContext(), bi));
                }
            }
        });
        Button histogram_color = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_color_btn);
        histogram_color.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (bi != null) {
                    isColored = true;
                    view_color = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyt_color);
                    view_color.addView(new MyHistogram(getApplicationContext(),
                            bi));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {

        case 101:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String filename = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
                bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
                /*
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,10,out);
                bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));*/

                if(bi!=null)
                {
                    try {
                        new MyAsync().execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        Log.e("TEST", "GetRealPath : " + contentUri);

        try {
            if (contentUri.toString().contains("video")) {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                load(bi);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageBitmap(bi);

            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_btn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.hst_color_btn)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            dismissDialog(0);
        }

    }

    public void load(Bitmap bi) throws IOException {

        if (bi != null) {
            // Reset all the bins
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    colourBins[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {

                    int pixel = bi.getPixel(x, y);

                    colourBins[RED][Color.red(pixel)]++;
                    colourBins[GREEN][Color.green(pixel)]++;
                    colourBins[BLUE][Color.blue(pixel)]++;
                }
            }

            maxY = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                    if (maxY < colourBins[i][j]) {
                        maxY = colourBins[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            loaded = true;
        } else {
            loaded = false;
        }
    }

    class MyHistogram extends View {

        public MyHistogram(Context context, Bitmap bi) {
            super(context);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (loaded) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);

                Log.e("NIRAV", "Height : " + getHeight() + ", Width : "
                        + getWidth());

                int xInterval = (int) ((double) getWidth() / ((double) SIZE + 1));

                for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_COLOURS; i++) {

                    Paint wallpaint;

                    wallpaint = new Paint();
                    if (isColored) {
                        if (i == RED) {
                            wallpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                        } else if (i == GREEN) {
                            wallpaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else if (i == BLUE) {
                            wallpaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        wallpaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    }

                    wallpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

                    Path wallpath = new Path();
                    wallpath.reset();
                    wallpath.moveTo(0, getHeight());
                    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - 1; j++) {
                        int value = (int) (((double) colourBins[i][j] / (double) maxY) * (getHeight()+100));


                         //if(j==0) { 
                        //   wallpath.moveTo(j * xInterval* offset, getHeight() - value); 
                         //} 
                        // else {
                             wallpath.lineTo(j * xInterval * offset, getHeight() - value);
                        // }
                    }
                    wallpath.lineTo(SIZE * offset, getHeight());
                    canvas.drawPath(wallpath, wallpaint);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
     protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            ProgressDialog dataLoadProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dataLoadProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
            dataLoadProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
            dataLoadProgress.setCancelable(false);
            dataLoadProgress.setProgressStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
            return dataLoadProgress;

        }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt"
            android:layout_width="257dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hst_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Histogram" 
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hst_color_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Color Histogram" 
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_color"
            android:layout_width="257dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Image"
            android:id="@+id/upload"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this example will help others also..!

Comment: what's the value for `offset`?

Comment: @User1204501 I have updated my answer please check, you will get to know the value for offset.

Comment: @User1204501 ..sorry i can't share my email id here, just google my full name you will get my contact info, you can contact me anytime.. but i would like to help you here so that it will also help to others who are stucked in this issue in future.

Comment: @User1204501 It might be crashing after calling load() method. So put load() method in Async class (generate separate thread don't use main thread). I hope this will solve your crashing error.

Comment: Also where have you used your load()

Comment: how is colourBins initialized?

Comment: @Zhenya.. Please review my answer, I have added my complete code. Hope this help you..!

Comment: @aav.. Please review my answer now !

Comment: @User1204501 Please review my answer.. I hope your all the queries would be solved now !